# PHP Array Multisort on Status

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to multisort a DB array based on the users status. Those with Status = 1 go at the top, those with Status = 0 go at the bottom of the array. I thought I had it working but it just stopped today with the addition of new rows to the DB.

```
uasort($ven, function ($a, $b) { return $a['v_status'] == '1' ? false : true; });
```

It's a simple DB array from MySQL:

```
Array (
 [0] => array(
   [name] => '',
   [v_status] => 0
 [1] => array(
   [name] => '',
   [v_status] => 1
)
```

Comment: Why not do the sort in the DB query?

Comment: DB Cannot sort, I need it to be in the PHP after the fact, I have my reasons thanks. No it cannot be - as it's a yes or no question, status = 1 (Active), status = 0 (Inactive). At least I think - won't work.

Comment: it is working fine .$x=array ( array('name' => 'a','v_status' => 0),array('name' => 'b','v_status' => 1), array('name' => 'a','v_status' => 0)
 
);
usort($x,function ($a, $b) { return $a['v_status'] == '1' ? false : true; });
print_r($x);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments to my other answer, splitting the array into active/inactive arrays could be a better solution than sorting.

```
$items = array(
    array('name' => 'active1', 'active' => '1'),
    array('name' => 'inactive1', 'active' => '0'),
    array('name' => 'active2', 'active' => '1'),
    array('name' => 'inactive2', 'active' => '0'),
    array('name' => 'inactive3', 'active' => '0'),
    array('name' => 'active3', 'active' => '1'),
    array('name' => 'inactive4', 'active' => '0'),
);

$active = array_filter($items, function($item){ return $item['active'] == '1'; });
echo '<pre>' . print_r($active,true);

// You could filter again here, not sure which would be quicker, 
// but my guess would be the array_diff method (which also ensures
// that no items get filtered out by both filters)
$inactive = array_diff_key($items, $active);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($inactive,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

uasort expects the callback to return a positive integer if $a should be above $b, a negative integer if $b should be above $a or 0 if they are equal.

This is why despite there only being 2 options Jon's suggestion `return $b['v_status'] - $a['v_status'];` is correct.

In your case if at some point during the sort $a[v_status] = 0 and $b[v_status] = 1 the function looks at $a[v_status], returns false, which equates to 0 and the algorithm (quick sort I think) treats them as equal and therefore leaves them in their current order.

See [PHP: usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for reference, which expects a similar callback.

Comment: Still doesn't work, same thing as before:
http://i.imgur.com/KLGYK5P.png
The only one that is inactive at this time is Vendor 2, the rest are "1".

Comment: How are you outputting the array? uasort leaves the indexes as is, so if you then loop through by index it will have the same order as before. Either use foreach when outputting the array, or use usort, which reindexes the array.

Comment: I've tried usort instead of uasort but same thing. I am using `foreach` in my output.

Comment: The output in the code example (comment 3) shows that arrays are sorted correctly if that function is used, so the error must be elsewhere, can you provide any more details that may help?

Comment: Since the aim is to split the output into active / inactive would using array_filter be an option? You would then have an active array and an inactive array to output. e.g. http://codepad.viper-7.com/3nMYXx

Comment: Just found the error, I'm using PHP 5.4 but Closure isn't working hence anon functions aren't working. Just figure this one out. But I like the array_filter option you just posted and would much rather use that. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept please?